# How to add a getter to an object

Tags: javascript

This probably has a prior answer, but I haven't been able to find it.

I have some code that gets data from a database and returns an entity such as:

```
   var customer1 = {first: "Greg", last: "Gum"};
```

How do I add a getter to this object so that I can call a FullName getter:

```
   var theFullName = customer1.fullName;
```

What I don't understand is the difference between adding a getter to an object, and adding a getter to a "class" so that it becomes available to all future objects of that type.  The thing is that the code that creates the object is a black box, so I don't really have access to that code.  I don't know the best way to resolve this.

Comment: "all future objects of that type" --- of what type? All those objects would be unique.

Comment: What's the code that gets the data that you show? Because I suspect that if it's truly a black box you'll have to add your own function somewhere that takes advantage of retrieving the first name and surname.

Comment: @zerkms I am thinking of them as "Customer" types, but I don't know if they are actually a class (as I would think of them in c#)

Comment: How are the JavaScript objects created?

Comment: @user2182349 That's the thing - the database layer is a library called breeze. They are being dynamically being created.  But the data factory does pass an instance to a method where I can add properties. That is what I am trying to hook into.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to define the property on the object literal that has been returned, simply use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var cdata = {first: 'Foo', last: 'Bar'}
Object.defineProperty(cdata, 'fullName', {
  get: function() { return this.first + ' ' + this.last; }
});

console.log(cdata.fullName); // Foo Bar
```

However, if you want to create a new object from the returned literal, one method would be:

```
function Customer(data) {
  var k;
  for (k of Object.keys(data)) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, k, {
      value: data[k]
    });
  }

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
    get: function() { return this.first + ' ' + this.last; }
  });
}

var cdata = {first: 'Foo', last: 'Bar'};
var customer = new Customer(cdata);

console.log(customer.fullName); // Foo Bar
```

But a more memory efficient method is:

```
function Customer(data) {
  var k;
  for (k of Object.keys(data)) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, k, {
      value: data[k]
    });
  }
}

Customer.prototype = {
  get fullName() {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
  }
};

var cdata = {first: 'Foo', last: 'Bar'};
var customer = new Customer(cdata);

console.log(customer.fullName); // Foo Bar
```

The first `Customer` definition adds an instance property `fullName` which will consume memory for each instance of `Customer` that is created. The second definition defines the `fullName` property as a prototype property, thus saving a small amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks! Of course, if you're using a `Customer` constructor, you should just put the getter on the prototype.

Comment: A note for TypeScript users: This answer works, but NOT if you use a fat arrow in the getter.  The proper way is to use `function()...` not `()=>...` as `this` is then correctly defined.

Comment: @Bergi both accomplish the same thing. This method just contains it all in one place.

Comment: @GregGum I suppose that's true. I have no use for `=>`, so it doesn't factor into the code I write.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: You are looking for this:

```
var customer1 = {first: "Greg", last: "Gum"};
Object.defineProperty(customer1, "fullName", {
  get: function() { return this.first + ' ' + this.last; }
});

var theFullName = customer1.fullName;
```

A more general aproach:

```
function addGetter(obj, name, func) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
      get: func
    });
}

var customer1 = {first: "Greg", last: "Gum"};
addGetter(customer1, "fullName", function() { return this.first + ' ' + this.last; } )

var theFullName = customer1.fullName;
```

You could even protoype Object to do sth like `customer1.getter("fullName", function() { return this.first + ' ' + this.last; } )`

---

OLD:
I have a nice way of doing it with TypeScript, it compiles to this JavaScript:

```
var Customer = (function () {
    function Customer(first, last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Customer.prototype, "fullName", {
        get: function () { return this.first + " " + this.last; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Customer;
})();
var customer1 = new Customer("Greg", "Gum");
var theFullName = customer1.fullName;
```

However the TypeScript looks way nicer:

```
class Customer {
    first: string
    last: string

    constructor(first: string, last: string) {
        this.first = first
        this.last = last        
    }

    get fullName() { return this.first + " " + this.last }
}

var customer1 = new Customer("Greg", "Gum")
var theFullName = customer1.fullName
```

You can play with it [**here**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Customer%20%7B%0D%0A%09first%3A%20string%0D%0A%09last%3A%20string%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(first%3A%20string%2C%20last%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.first%20%3D%20first%0D%0A%09%09this.last%20%3D%20last%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09get%20fullName()%20%7B%20return%20this.first%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20this.last%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20customer1%20%3D%20new%20Customer(%22Greg%22%2C%20%22Gum%22)%0D%0Avar%20theFullName%20%3D%20customer1.fullName)

Comment: I am actually using Typescript, but I don't want a function, I want a property as it is being used with binding, and a property is required, not a function.

Comment: `get fullName() { return this.first + " " + this.last }` might be an option? Use it like this: `var theFullName = customer1.fullName`

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I am looking for.  But how do I add it to the object?

Comment: I updated the class in my Answer. But you don't want to use a class?

Comment: Like I said, I can't use a class because there is no actual class called "Customer": it is being dynamically created.

Comment: OK. Then you will have to add the function to the Object, in the same style as the JavaScript above.

Comment: Your answer was really good, but I think that James had the answer first.  Would you agree?

Comment: i dont know, but when comparing, this answere might be more helpfull for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

One way you can solve this is to create your own wrapper class `Customer` that wraps the received object and adds the getter.

Furthermore, you want to add the getter on the prototype of your `Costumer` class so that it is only defined once and available for all future instances. Something like:

```
function Customer(c) {
    this.firstName = c.first;
    this.lastName = c.last;
}

Customer.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

And you will use it like:

```
var c = getCustomerFromBlackBox();
var customer = new Customer(c);
```

---

If you are using ES6, then you can take advantage of its more robust syntax:

```
class Customer {

  constructor(c) {
    this.firstName = c.first;
    this.lastName = c.last;
  }

  fullName() { 
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

---

Based on your comment that you want to edit the received object itself, well then you can do just that:

```
var c = getCustomerFromBlackBox();

if(typeof c === 'object' && c !== null) {     // make sure c is an object
    c.getFullName = function() {              // add a getter
        return this.first + " " + this.last;
    }
}
```

Do note that this will add the getter code to **every** object you receive and thus will take more memory.

Also, since you don't know how this object is created, you might want to add checks to make sure `first` and `last` strings to actually exist and perhaps add specific values in case they don't.

---

**EDIT**:

Since you said in your comment that you know that your `first` and `last` names will **never** change, and that you want a property rather than a getter function, you can literally just add this property each time you read a customer:

```
var c = getCustomerFromBlackBox();
c.fullName = c.first + " " + c.last; // Can also add same checks to make sure c is an object and c.first and c.last are strings
```

Again, this is added to **every** object and has a similar memory overhead as adding a direct getter function (and not on the prototype)

---

A good approach that I missed is using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) as shown in [James Sumner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33862264/3928341).

```
Object.defineProperty(c, 'fullName', {
  get: function() { return this.first + " " + this.last; }
});
```

This approach adds the property directly on the object (not the prototype) and additionally makes the property **immutable** meaning you cannot accidentally delete it.

Comment: I don't want to wrap it.  I just want to add a property to the object.

Comment: Closer, but I don't want a function, I want a getter, as it is used with binding and it requires a getter, not a function. :)

Comment: not sure I understand you. A getter is just that, a function. If `first` or `last` change, calling `getFullName` will return the reflected changes.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a getter, but I think `var fullName = customer.fullName` is different than 'var fullName = customer.fullName()'

Comment: Well yes, but that is then **just a property, not a getter**. In this case, you can just set your `fullName` to be `c.fullName = c.first + " " + c.last` when you create your costumer but then if you change first or last, the changes won't reflect in the `fullName` and you have to change the `fullName` manually as well. By using a getter function you save yourself maintaining changes at multiple places. Additionally, by using the wrapper class like I suggested you are also saving memory (especially if you have a lot of customers) by creating the getter only once (on the prototype).

Comment: that is actually a really good point - I can just create it once at object creation and be done with it.  It doesn't matter in this case if it does not get updated later.

Comment: Yup, if you know for a fact `first` and `last` will never change, you could just literally add this property (as I've shown in my last edit). However, do be aware of the limitations this approach brings and that it makes the code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a constructor to use prototypal inheritance in JavaScript.

E.g. like below. Check [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ageo43rb/).

```
var customer1Data = {first: "Greg", last: "Gum"};

var Customer = function(customerData ) {
    this.first = customer1Data.first;
    this.last = customer1Data.last;
}

Customer.prototype.fullName = function() {
   return this.first + ' '+this.last;
}

var customer1 = new Customer(customer1Data );
```

Comment: I don't want to add a new class.  I just want to add a property to the object.

Comment: Can you then add `customer1.fullName = function() { return this.first + ' '+this.last; }`  to your object? This won't make it inheritable though.  Like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ageo43rb/3/)

Comment: I need a getter, not a function.

Comment: What about `customer1.fullName = customer1.first + '  '+customer1.last;` ? :) Or what is a getter then?

Comment: It's only because it's being used in a binding context, and the syntax requires a getter syntax, not function syntax.

Comment: OK. I guess you decided to stick to the `customer1.fullName = customer1.first + ' '+customer1.last` option.